# How to get hovering shadow under a letter with CSS-only?

Tags: css

I would like to reproduce the following logo, add a shadow below one letter as in the [image: Probe Logo] using only CSS.

How to do it as box-shadow overflow on both side of the letter ? I would prefer to avoid having an extra `<span class="shadow"></span>` following my "hovering" letter but manage it only with the letter tag/CSS rule (see HTML below).

**N.B.:** I'm aware of [jQuery / CSS3 Animated shadow effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14313863/802365).

#### HTML

```
<span>Pr<span class="text-info">o</span>be</span>
```

#### CSS

```
element.style {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 3px #AAAAAA;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it without another element because you can't decrease the shadow's width relative to the entire span, but you could do it with a pseudoelement if that's better: http://jsfiddle.net/Xysax/1/

Comment: I would do this with another image. easy and effective.

Comment: As FYI: I have updated the solution, here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/v9k6Q/

Comment: Both solutions exhibit similar issues: 
- shadow appear on 3 sides. The shadow below the letter is truncated on top giving an akward look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Technique

- I had to **use pseudo-element** as described by @Alex Bell.
- But instead of `box-shadow` I use `text-shadow` and tweak the pseudo-element position.
- pseudo-element text is `ˍ` aka `U+02CD MODIFIER LETTER LOW MACRON` (`&#717;` or `\u02CD`)

Final [result is available **as a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9k6Q/8/).

### HTML

```
<div class="text-effects">
    <span>Pr<span class="text-info">o</span>be</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    font-size: 10em;
    font-family: Arial;
}

div.text-effects {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

span.text-info {
    position: relative;
    color: #008080;
    bottom: 0.1em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}

span.text-info:after {
    bottom: 0.15em;
    color: transparent;
    content: "ˍ";
    display: block;
    font-size: 120px !important;
    height: 1em;
    left: 26%;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 0 11px #999;
    width: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using pseudo-elements (:`before` and :`after`), :`hover` and `opacity` properties, the solution looks like the following (it can be extended w/animation effects on `opacity`)

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-effects"><span>Pr<span class="text-info">o</span>be</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size: 10em;
    font-family: Arial;
}

div.text-effects {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

span.text-info {
    position: relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.text-info:hover {
    color: #008080;
    bottom: 0.1em;
}

span.text-info:before {
    content: ".";
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 4px -4px #303030;
    display: block;
    left: 30%;
    bottom: 1em;
    opacity:0;
}
span.text-info:after {
    content: ".";
    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 40%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 4px -4px #303030;
    display: block;
    left: 30%;
    bottom:0.15em;
    opacity:0;
}

span.text-info:hover:before{
    opacity:1;
}

span.text-info:hover:after{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I express myself badly, I don't want the effect on-mouse-over but a shadow below the letter in a similar fashion as if it was hovering a few cm above the ground

Comment: In this case, if I understand correctly, you can remove all that :hover events and also remove opacity:0; Then adjust the bottom:1em; property of the pseudo-element :before per your requirement.

Comment: Yep, the pseudo-element hint was what I was missing, see my answer.